# CodeIgniter : custom config file error-does not appear to contain a valid configuration array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, routes, config

I require an config file in my route.php

```
require "agent.php";
```

and this report some error

> Your application/config/agent.php file does not appear to contain a
>   valid configuration array.

this is my agent.php file's code

```
<?

$config['agent_route'] = "zhutest1|zhutest2|zhutest3|livwyy|beyoung";

$config['agent_aid_ary'] = array(
"zhutest1" => "2",
"zhutest2" => "3",
"zhutest3" => "4",
"livwyy" => "9",
"beyoung" => "11",
);

$config['agent_username_ary'] = 
array(
"2" => "zhutest1",
"3" => "zhutest2",
"4" => "zhutest3",
"9" => "livwyy",
"11" => "beyoung",
);


$config['gender']= array ('male','female');

?>
```

can't config array variable use key value array?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use require('agent.php');

in codeigniter you can use

```
$this->config->load('agent');
```

and then use your custom config array as such :-

```
$this->config->item('agent_username_ary');
```

make sure the agent.php is inside the config folder and that each config key name is unique

Read the docs for more info https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/config.html